# Explicit Sorting for datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I have a column in my datatable that contains status information (i.e. very good, good, ok, bad, very bad), and I'd like to sort by status, not alphabetically. How do I do that?

I just made up this property, but is there something like this?

```
$("#myTable").DataTable({
    "sortArray": ['very good', 'good', 'ok', 'bad', 'very bad']
});
```

I did look through the datatables documentation and found [custom sorting](http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html), but it uses types such as alphabetic and numeric, as far as I can tell.

EDIT: I can't use HTML5 because this must be compatible with IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1**

You can use [columnDefs](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) to target a specific column using zero-based index in `targets` option and [columnDefs.render](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to return numerical value during sorting (`type === 'sort'`). jQuery helper method [$.inArray()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) is used to return array index based on the value provided.

```
$('#myTable').dataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": 0,
            "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                if(type === 'sort'){
                   var values = ['very good', 'good', 'ok', 'bad', 'very bad'];
                   data = $.inArray(data, values);
                }

                return data;
            }
        }
    ]
} );
```

---

**SOLUTION 2**

Alternative solution is to use `data-` attributes as shown in [HTML5 data-* attributes](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) example.

If you have static HTML data, you could create your rows as shown below, then jQuery DataTables picks up `data-` attributes and uses them for searching.

```
<tr>
    <td>T. Nixon</td>
    <td>System Architect</td>
    <td data-order="1">very good</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>T. Nixon</td>
    <td>System Architect</td>
    <td data-order="2">good</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution - that seems pretty straightforward. I should have clarified: the status is not static - I won't know which cells are "very good", "good, etc while making the table. I also can't use HTML 5 because this has to work in IE9.....

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize at first that they're 2 separate solutions. The first solution works perfectly - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a numeric value to each of your statuses (i.e. 1 -> very good, 2 -> good, and so on) and then use the column rendering capabilities of DataTables to map back your numeric value to a text status.

[DataTables Column rendering](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html)

Comment: That's a good idea! I understand what you mean and conceptually what to do, but I'm not sure how to get started coding it....Would I do something like `"render": function.......if( data === "very good") return 1; else if( data === "good") return 2;` ..... ?